# vCenter logon failing using Get-VICredentialStoreItem from Azure automation runbooking with hybrid worker

Tags: azure, azure-runbook, vcenter, hybrid-runbook-worker

We are using Azure automation runbook using hybrid worker and trying to collect information from on-prem vcenter environment. We are using Get-VICredentialStoreItem to logon to vcenter but logon itself using stored credentials is failing from runbook. When I use this script locally on hybrid worker server it works fine.

The error we are getting is that it can't find the path(most likely for xml file) so it can't logon to vcenter server. Screenshot of error is below.
My understanding is that the script runs locally in hybrid worker server so if it is not complaning about path locally then why would this be causing an issue while running from runbook hybrid worker.

```
$date = get-date -format dd-MM-yyyy

#Load Module and connect to vCenter

Get-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI.VCenter* -ListAvailable | Import-Module
Get-Module -Name VMware.Sdk* -ListAvailable | Import-Module 
Get-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Import-Module

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false -Confirm:$false
 
$Credentials = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Host "server1.domain.local" -File "\\mgmtserver.domain.local\Credentials\pwd.xml"

Connect-viserver -server "server1.domain.local" -User $Credentials.User -Password $Credentials.Password

$datastore = "\\mgmtserver.domain.local\myshare2\VMware-Corp-Datastores.csv"

#add VMtools details 
New-VIProperty -Name ToolsVersion -ObjectType VirtualMachine -ValueFromExtensionProperty 'Config.tools.ToolsVersion' -Force 
New-VIProperty -Name ToolsVersionStatus -ObjectType VirtualMachine -ValueFromExtensionProperty 'Guest.ToolsVersionStatus' -Force

#export datastore list
get-datastore | Select Name, Datacenter, CapacityGB, FreeSpaceGB | export-csv $datastore -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

disconnect-viserver -Server * -confirm:$false
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRMMZ.jpg)

The system cannot find the path specified.

A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Please specify server credential

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, credentials have to be created using same account that is going to use it in Automation account.